# How to set sort order for clustering key in DSE graph?

Tags: cassandra, datastax

In this below query how do I set the sort order as descending for the clustering key?

```
schema().vertexLabel('FridgeSensor').partitionKey('city_id').clusteringKey('sensor_id').create()
```

Comment: Your table should already be sorting by the clustering key.  Unfortunately, you can't pick arbitrary columns to order your results by.

Comment: @Aaron I understand that clustering key automatically sorts in ascending order. However, my question is how do I change the sort order to be descending when data is being created. This is possible in plain Cassandra, but not sure how to do it in graph.